# Why does my jQuery not work in Internet Explorer 6?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I am designing a webpage, and I am using jQuery.

The webpage makes use of Ajax. Internet Explorer 6 and lower versions do not show the page correctly. Even the Ajax code doesn't seem to work.

#### Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Hide all sub heading lists
    $("#content1").load("sub/image1.html");
    $("li[@id^='cont']").click(function(){
         var current_id=$(this).attr('id');
         switch(current_id){
             case 'content_1':$("#content1").load("sub/my.html");break;
             default:;
         }
    });
});
```

The code works perfectly in Internet Explorer 7, Internet Explorer 8, Chrome and Firefox. In Internet Explorer 6 or below it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you might have to give some more information about what you're trying to do.  jQuery should support IE 6, so there could be something else going on.  What piece of code no longer works?  Could you paste it into your question?

Comment: I agree to Damovisa, you have to give more information to get this thing worked out ^^

Comment: case 'content_1':$("#content1").load("sub/my.html");break;. Did you really put all of this in 1 line? #1 rule of readable code: Where there is a ; there should be a new line.

Comment: Problem is found out some of windowsserver2003 version ie behaves silly .. because bad ie

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure why it doesn't work, but you could try upgrading jQuery to version 1.3.

If you've already upgraded to 1.3, then your script will be failing because the `@` before the attribute name was deprecated in jQuery 1.2.  Take it out and see how that goes.

```
$("li[id^='cont']").click(function() { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas:

- Instead of `jQuery(document).ready()` , try using  `$(document).ready()`.
- The line: `$("li[@id^='cont']")` might be the one causing the issue in IE 6. It seems like you are just trying to select all the `<li>` items where the id starts with `cont`. Instead you can try to give all the `<li>s` a class such as `contLi` and then the code:

  `$(".contLi")`
  will select the same `<li>s` as before, and it may also work in IE 6.

Comment: Since I Have using Javascript Accordion it Must for me use jQuery(document).ready()..

Comment: $ === jQuery, unless you're doing something weird.

Comment: If they have something else on the page that uses $() (prototype, for instance) then they probably put jQuery in noConflict, which means they need to use jQuery(), not $()

Answer (score 0):

It may be something to do with `default:;`. I've found in the past that Internet Explorer 6 sometimes doesn't like you leaving something empty when there should be something there, even if it's not technically incorrect.

So try `default: break;`.